# Please explain the answer to this polar-cartesian problem

Tags: calculus

If $r>0$ and $0< \theta <2\pi$, then the polar coordinates of the Cartesian point $(2, [-2 * 3^{1/2}] )$ are ___________.

The answer is $(4, 5\pi/3).$

I don't understand how they came up with $5\pi/3$. My answer was $2\pi/3$, because when you take the $(y/x)$ of $2\pi/3$, you will come up with $-3^{1/2}$.

Comment: What´s the question?? What does "0_ _____" mean?

Comment: I think you need http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: @DonAntonio Whenever someone posts an expression including the character `<` sandwiched between two characters, anything after the < in the paragraph of question does not render.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2, -2\sqrt3)\implies r^2=4+12=16\implies r =4\;,\;\;\theta=\arctan\frac{-2\sqrt3}2=-\frac\pi3$$

The angle must be s.t. that we get a point in the fourth quadrant and thus either $\;-\frac\pi2<\theta<0\;$ 
 or $\;\frac{3\pi}2<\theta<2\pi\;$

If you don't want $\;-\frac\pi3\;$ add $\;2\pi\;$ and get $\;\frac{5\pi}3\;$ .

Comment: How do I know that the part that "I need to get a point in the fourth quadrant"? Where in the problem does it state such? Sorry, I just thought 0<θ<2π means any angle from 0 to 2π which means my answer 2π/3 was acceptable.

Comment: @Gannicus, No: it's not acceptable. A point $\;(x,y)\;$ with $\;x>0>y\;$ is in the fourth quadrant. Period.